# DNN - make new pages viewable to All Users by default

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have a DNN 7 site. For new pages that are created in the portals, we want "All Users" to be checked under View Page by default.

How do we do this? I *think* I've found the right template file:

/Portals/_default/Templates/Default.page.template

But I can't find any documentation about the tags therein.

It does have:

```
          <inheritviewpermissions>true</inheritviewpermissions>
```

But where are the view permissions inherited from?  And how to override them?

Again, we want it so that new pages are viewable to all users by default; no need to go change anything after new page creation. (Yeah, I know, but that's the requirement.)

Comment: Have you tried creating a new page template with the permissions already configured on the page you're creating the template from?

Comment: I tried creating a new page template based on an existing page, so I could get the right XML fields. I couldn't just use the new template file itself though, as I want to change the default permissions of the very basic default page template. I tried copying what looks like the right XML fields, but it didn't work.

Comment: It likely ignores the template's permissions and uses the permissions configured on the Permissions grid while creating a page. I beleive the only way you will get that to work is by making a core change to DNN